# JavaScript drag and drop works in Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I made function exchanging two div backgrounds via drag and drop. It works well in Chrome, but if I operate it in IE, then it crashes down.

Here is the HTML part:

```
 <div class="slot" id="slot1" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event,0)" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event,0)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event,0)" onclick="removecard(0)"></div>
 <div class="slot" id="slot2" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event,1)" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event,1)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event,1)" onclick="removecard(1)"></div>
 <div class="slot" id="slot3" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event,2)" ondragenter="onDragEnter(event,2)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event,2)" onclick="removecard(2)"></div>
```

Here is the JavaScript part:

```
function onDragStart(ev,a){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("DraggingIndex",a);
}

function onDragEnter(ev,a){
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function onDragOver(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function onDrop(ev,b){
    var a = ev.dataTransfer.getData("DraggingIndex");
    slotchange(a,b);
           deckexpression(deck);
}
```

It worked well in Chrome, but in IE, it doesn't work. I guess that in IE, onDragStart or onDrop function could not handle two parameters. My aim is to operate slotchange(a,b) where a and b are indices of two slots.

Please teach me how to solve the problem in IE. Thanks.

Comment: What does slot change do, does it perform an AJAX operation?

Comment: @WheretheresaWill No, it is just another JavaScript function, exchanging corresponding data related to two boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using? 
**Internet Explorer 9+ supports drag and drop.**

Here is a sample of onDragStart and onDrop having 2 parameters, working on IE:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 1)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div class='slot' id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, 2)" width="336"   height="69">   </div>
```

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
}

function drag(ev, secondParam) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    console.log(secondParam);
}

function drop(ev, secondParam) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   console.log(secondParam)
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amontellano/8twY6/

Comment: My IE version was 11, but I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: What I want is to CONVERT information of secondParam of drag to drop(ev). How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you mention "CONVERT" ?
Consider you are handling number indexes ( such as 0,1,2) for secondParam and the name(id) of your HTML elements are using the prefix "slot". Maybe you can get your elements with var elem = document.getElementById("slot" + param);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE only supports setting "Text" and "URL".

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536744(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My workaround for setting multiple values was:

```
var data = {
   id: ev.target.id, 
   dragIndex: index
};
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then you'll have to parse it when dropped:

```
var data = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
console.log(data.id);
console.log(data.dragIndex);
```

Comment: Another thing I´ve noticed is that if I add a listener to "ondragenter" the event does not provide the data. ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text") is an empty string where as other browsers provides the same object as when dropped :(